# How to determine if one or more column in a large text file is sorted or not sorted

Tags: perl, bash, unix, cmd

I have greater than 1GB big text file. The file has 4 columns delimited by TAB.

```
Col1: Guid
Col2: Date-time (yy-mm-yyyy 0000000000)
Col3: String
Col4: String
```

I want to determine if one or more of its column are sorted or not sorted.

Is there any quick way to do that? Maybe using Perl or some unix command? Or anything similar?

I have files on large servers and on my local windows machine, so memory or cpu speed or OS is not an issue.

Comment: Sorting what? Integers? Words? Sounds like a tricky perl/bash/awk one liner. I would do it in python, more maintainable and scalable.

Comment: Yes, you could write a short (<15 lines, very rough estimate) perl script doing just that, if that's what you meant by "quick". But since you already suggest perl I suppose you knew about that.

Comment: I just updated the question with column type details

Comment: Nevermind, @Satish solution is great, go with that one. Could try putting it in a script saving the unsorted_file.dat with mktemp.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use the `-c` option of `sort` to check for sorted order and the `-k` to specify on which column:

```
$ sort -c -k2,2 file
sort: file:2: disorder: Col2: Date-time (yy-mm-yyyy 0000000000)
```

Or `-C` to suppress output and test the exit code. You may also want to specify the type of sort depending on the data like `-n` for numeric sort `-v` for version sort, ect.

Answer (score 4):

Many versions of `sort` have an option to check whether a file is sorted or not. For example, using the version on my laptop (Debian), I can do this:

```
if sort -C -k 2,2 somefile
then
  # something
else
  # something else
fi
```

to check whether the second column of a file is sorted. The exit code of `sort` indicates success or failure.

Answer (score 3):

first determine the column
then use awk

```
awk '{print $2}' OFS="\t" test.tmp > unsorted_file.dat
```

for second column

```
awk '{print $2}' OFS="\t" test.tmp | sort > sorted_file.dat

diff sorted_file.dat unsorted_file.dat
```

Answer (score 1):

Just split the line into columns and compare them with the values in the previous line. If the previous value is greater than the one in the current line, the column is not sorted.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @sorted = (1, 1, 1, 1);
my $first = <>; # read the first line
my @prev = split(/\t/, $first);

while (<>) {
    my @cols = split(/\t/);
    for (my $i = 0; $i < 4; ++$i) {
        $sorted[$i] = 0 if ($prev[$i] gt $cols[$i]);
    }

    @prev = @cols;
}

for (my $i = 0; $i < 4; ++$i) {
    my $not = $sorted[$i] ? '' : 'not ';
    print "Column $i is $not sorted\n";
}
```

Test file.txt

```
a   a   a   a
b   b   b   b
c   c   c   c
d   d   d   d
e   e   e   a
f   d   f   f
g   g   g   g
```

Call as

```
perl script.pl file.txt
```

will give you

> Column 0 is  sorted
>   Column 1 is not  sorted
>   Column 2 is  sorted
>   Column 3 is not  sorted

This compares textually and tests for ascending order. If you need another order or a different comparison, you must adapt the inner for loop accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the solution with examples!